# nightwatchJS logs where are they stored?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a question about where my test log files are stored. 
I want to see the log files, which display in Webstorm or in the console.

[image: Screenshot]

To see if all my assertions did run, which failed, which passed etc..

I added to `nightwatch.conf.js`:

```
"chrome": {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "loggingPrefs": {
                "browser": "ALL"
            },
```

I added to the test:

```
login
.navigate()
.loginToDomain(username, password)
        browser.getLogTypes(function(result) {
        console.log(result); 
        [ 'browser', 'driver', 'client', 'server' ]
    });
    browser.getLog('browser', function(logEntriesArray) {
            logEntriesArray.forEach(function(log) {
                console.log('[' + log.level + '] ' + log.timestamp + ' : ' + log.message);
            })
        })
    browser.end();
```

My question is where does this store the logs and where do I need to define it?

In the reports folder, I see logs but not the output from the console.
Thanks in advance!